# Is there a way to get a compile-time error if there's no matching closed type family instance?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, type-level-computation

I have a closed type family which has no catch-all case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Foo a where
    Foo Bool = Int
    Foo Int = Bool
```

Is there a way to force the type checker to reject the following program:

```
data T a = MkT deriving Show

x :: T (Foo String)
x = MkT
```

on account of the fact that there is no `Foo String` type?

Comment: No, but there should be.  There should be an error function on the type level.  I've submitted a ghc feature request quite a while ago.

Comment: @augustss: you mean I should be able to write a catch-all case `Foo a = Error "You dun goofed up"`? Because that would be awesome. What is the GHC Trac ticket # for that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9637 and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CustomTypeErros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from GHC 8.0.1, it's possible to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

type family Foo a where
    Foo Bool = Int
    Foo Int  = Bool
    Foo a    = TypeError (Text "Invalid Foo " :<>: ShowType a)

data T a = MkT deriving Show

x :: T (Foo String)
x = MkT
```

Module can be loaded, yet you cannot use `x`:

```
*Main> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( te.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> x

<interactive>:18:1: error:
    • Invalid Foo [Char]
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: T (TypeError ...)
```

If you add, without a type signature

```
y = id x
```

the GHC(i) while complain during type-check:

```
te.hs:15:1: error:
    • Invalid Foo [Char]
    • When checking the inferred type
        y :: T (TypeError ...)
```

Yet, if you give `y` a type: `y :: T (Foo String)`; then GHC will accept that as well.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or feature. Type families, even closed one, cannot be arbitrarily reduced, especially in presence of `UndecidableInstances`, which one needs to use `TypeError` in the first place. And even something like whnf is probably not enough, if type family would reduce to `Maybe (TypeError ...)`.